# Example of topological space that is not first countable and also is not separable

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, separable-spaces, first-countable

I want to find a topological space that is not first countable and is not separable. Cofinite topology is not first countable but is separable. Please help me.

Comment: $[0,\omega_1$]. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_space#Ordinal_space

Comment: If $X$ is your space which is not first countable, and $Y$ is some space which is not separable (say an uncountable discrete space), then the topological sum $X+Y$ is neither first countable nor separable.

Comment: The one-point compactification of an uncountable discrete space is a compact Hausdorff space which is neither first countable nor separable. In other words, take an uncountable set $X$, choose a point $a\in X$, and call a subset $U$ of $X$ *open* if either $a\notin U$ or $U$ is cofinite.